# TCP interception in kernel mode Windows Filtering Platform

Tags: c++, networking, wfp

I have following question: I'm trying to implement (as for now) printing with KdPrint in debugger all TCP connections that are appearing since the launching of a driver. I'm using Stream V4 Layer for it without any filter (because it's already TCP, yes?) and with functions declared in a callout I intercept every packet and KdPrint info about Local IP, Local Port, Remote IP and Remote Port. Unfortunately nothing appears in the debugger, only messages with "nothing to do I/O".

Here is the code:
Initialize Callout:

```
static NTSTATUS InitializeCallout(PDEVICE_OBJECT deviceObject)
{
    FWPM_SUBLAYER subLayer = {};
    subLayer.displayData.name = const_cast<wchar_t*>(L"TcpInterception Sub-Layer");
    subLayer.subLayerKey = TCP_INTERCEPTION_SUBLAYER;

    NTSTATUS status = FwpmSubLayerAdd(g_engineHandle, &subLayer, nullptr);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        return status;
    }

    FWPS_CALLOUT0 sCallout =
    {
        TCP_INTERCEPTION_TRANSPORT_V4_CALLOUT,
        0,
        CalloutConnectClassifyFn,
        CalloutNotifyFn,
        nullptr
    };

    status = FwpsCalloutRegister0(deviceObject, &sCallout, &g_id);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        return status;
    }

    FWPM_CALLOUT mCallout = {};
    mCallout.calloutKey = TCP_INTERCEPTION_TRANSPORT_V4_CALLOUT;
    mCallout.applicableLayer = FWPM_LAYER_STREAM_V4;
    mCallout.displayData.name = const_cast<wchar_t*>(g_displayName);

    status = FwpmCalloutAdd(g_engineHandle, &mCallout, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        return status;
    }

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        return status;
    }

    return status;
}
```

And the crucial CalloutConnectClassifyFn:

```
static void CalloutConnectClassifyFn(
    const FWPS_INCOMING_VALUES0* inFixedValues,
    const FWPS_INCOMING_METADATA_VALUES0* inMetaValues,
    void* layerData,
    const FWPS_FILTER0* filter,
    UINT64 /*flowContext*/,
    FWPS_CLASSIFY_OUT0* classifyOut)
{
    // Allowing the traffic for another filter to make a final decision.
    if (FlagOn(classifyOut->rights, FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE))
    {
        classifyOut->actionType = FWP_ACTION_CONTINUE;
    }

    if (layerData)
    {
        ProcessTransportData(inFixedValues, inMetaValues, layerData, classifyOut);
    }

    // Callout function should clear the FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE flag when it returns FWP_ACTION_BLOCK for the suggested action
    // and if FWPS_FILTER_FLAG_CLEAR_ACTION_RIGHT flag is set
    if (FWP_ACTION_BLOCK == classifyOut->actionType || FlagOn(filter->flags, FWPS_FILTER_FLAG_CLEAR_ACTION_RIGHT))
    {
        ClearFlag(classifyOut->rights, FWPS_RIGHT_ACTION_WRITE);
    }
}
```

And finally ProcessTransportData:

```
static void ProcessTransportData(const FWPS_INCOMING_VALUES0* inFixedValues,
    const FWPS_INCOMING_METADATA_VALUES0* inMetaValues,
    void* layerData,
    FWPS_CLASSIFY_OUT0* classifyOut)
{

    UINT32 localAddress = inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_OUTBOUND_TRANSPORT_V4_IP_LOCAL_ADDRESS].value.uint32;
    UINT32 remoteAddress = inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_OUTBOUND_TRANSPORT_V4_IP_REMOTE_ADDRESS].value.uint32;
    UINT16 localPort = inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_OUTBOUND_TRANSPORT_V4_IP_LOCAL_PORT].value.uint16;
    UINT16 remotePort = inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_OUTBOUND_TRANSPORT_V4_IP_REMOTE_PORT].value.uint16;

    
    if (inFixedValues->incomingValue[FWPS_FIELD_STREAM_V4_DIRECTION].value.uint32 == FWP_DIRECTION_INBOUND)
    {
        KdPrint(("Inbound connection\n"));
    }
    else
    {
        KdPrint(("Outbound connection\n"));
    }
    KdPrint(("Local IP: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", localAddress & 0xFF, (localAddress >> 8) & 0xFF, (localAddress >> 16) & 0xFF, (localAddress >> 24) & 0xFF));
    KdPrint(("Remote IP: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", remoteAddress & 0xFF, (remoteAddress >> 8) & 0xFF, (remoteAddress >> 16) & 0xFF, (remoteAddress >> 24) & 0xFF));
    KdPrint(("Local Port: %d\n", localPort));
    KdPrint(("Remote Port: %d\n", remotePort));
}
```

Do you have any suggestions, solutions to this problem? Thanks for helping

Comment: Calling `KdPrint()` alone is not enough; you also need to [enable the appropriate filter mask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/reading-and-filtering-debugging-messages#setting-the-component-filter-mask). I prefer [using WPP for kernel-mode tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-wpp-software-tracing-to-a-windows-driver) as it is configurable in user-mode without a kernel debugger.